# google play console Issue found: Unable to verify core functionality of app

Tags: flutter, google-play-console, user-permissions

Issue found: Unable to verify core functionality of app
Your declared that your permission use case is the core functionality of your app.

However, after review, we found that your app does not match the declared use case(s).

Learn more about permitted uses and exceptions.

Please either make changes to your app so that it meets the requirements of the declared core functionality or select a use case that matches your app’s functionality.

The video you submitted does not demonstrate the functionality necessary to verify and approve your use case declaration (for example, if your app uses SMS for account verification, your video should clearly show this).

```
SMS_BASED_TRANSACTION_APP
```

My application to have access only to the following permissions :

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, 
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, 
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.CAMERA, 
android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS, 
android.permission.READ_CONTACTS, 
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED, 
android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM, android.permission.SEND_SMS, 
android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC, android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT, 
android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT, android.permission.VIBRATE, 
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK, 
android.permission.WRIT[enter image description here]E_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
co.ysys.floosak.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION, 
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE, 
com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE, 
com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID
```

"Why do I see on Google Play that one of the cloned versions of my application contains the following permissions: `android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS and android.permission.SEND_SMS?"`

I have sent a video containing instructions for accessing the permission to send messages.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYgCi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyqbV.png)

Comment: Were you able t get your app accepted?
If yes, then what did you do?
Currently, Google Play Console is really frustrating me